# Create 2 documents when posting to CouchDB

Tags: database, couchdb, normalization

Is this possible? I'd like to normalize some data I'm storing in CouchDB, to take in one JSON object and, through designdocs, create multiple documents with different pieces of the data.

An example would be posting data about a book. I'd like to create a document for the book, check and see if there's any information about a publisher and if we have a document for that publisher, and if we don't, create a document for the publisher as well.

Does CouchDB have any functionality that would accomplish this? I know I could split up the data on the client, but I'd rather this logic be more centralized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post multiple docs at once with the [bulk docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#inserting-documents-in-bulk) endpoint, but it doesn't contain any logic like you're describing. That must be done on the client.